# How to position positive value on top and negative value on bottom of stacked bar in chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

The `formatter` function gives me the total of each group of stacked bars, I am trying to do the `datalabels` positioning it up if the total is positive and positioning it down if it is negative. Please any help would be very grateful.

[image]

```
datalabels: {
    anchor: (context) =>{
        const anchor = [];
        let sum = ?;
        
        if(parseFloat(sum) >=0){
            anchor.push('end');
        }else{
            anchor.push('start');
        }
        return anchor;
    },
    align: (context) =>{
        const align = [];
        let sum = ?;

        if(parseFloat(sum) >=0){
            align.push('end');
        }else{
            align.push('bottom');
        }
        return align;

    },
    formatter:(value, context) =>{
        const datasetArray = [];
        context.chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) =>{
            if(dataset.data[context.dataIndex] != undefined){
                datasetArray.push(dataset.data[context.dataIndex]);
            }
            
        });
        
        function totalSum(total, datapoint){                                           
            return +total + +datapoint;
        }
        
        let sum = datasetArray.reduce(totalSum);
        if(context.datasetIndex === datasetArray.length - 1){
            return parseFloat(sum).toFixed(2) ;
        }else{
            return '';
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: Could you please create a minimum reproducible example in CodeSandbox or similar tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear at this point how the bars are stacked - there are many unknown options. A possible combination based on the visual appearance of the image chart could be the following:

```js
const N = 10;
const dataGenerator = (plus = 600, minus = 400, pNull = 1) =>
    Array.from({length: N}, ()=>Math.random() < pNull ?
        Math.round(Math.random()*(plus+minus)-minus)/4 : null)
const ctx1 = document.getElementById('chart1');
new Chart(ctx1, {
    type: "bar",
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
    data: {
        labels: Array.from({length: N}, (_, i)=>'l'+(i+1)),
        datasets: [
            {
                data: dataGenerator(),
                stack: 'a',
            },
            {
                data: dataGenerator() ,
                stack: 'a',
            },
            {
                data: dataGenerator(100, 50, 0.5),
                stack: 'a',
            },
        ]
    },
    options: {
        indexAxis: 'x',
        layout: {
            padding: {
                top: 20,
                bottom: 20
            }
        },
        animation: {
            duration: 0
        },
        scales: {
            x: {
                ticks:{
                    display: false
                }
            },
            y: {
                stacked: true,
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        },
        plugins:{
            legend:{
                display: false
            },
            datalabels:{
                formatter: (value, context) => {
                    const {dataIndex, datasetIndex, chart} = context;
                    const dataForDataIndex = chart.data.datasets.map(
                        dataset=>dataset.data[dataIndex] ?? 0
                    );
                    const total = dataForDataIndex.reduce((s, x)=>s+x)
                    // the index of the dataset that contains the last point (at dataIndex)
                    // with the same sign as the total - that is the one that should carry
                    // the total label
                    const datasetIndexLast = dataForDataIndex.findLastIndex(x => x * total > 0);
                    context.total = total;
                    return datasetIndexLast === datasetIndex ? total.toFixed(2) : null
                },
                anchor: (context) => {
                    return context.total > 0 ? 'end' : 'start'
                },
                align: (context) => {
                    return context.total > 0 ? 'top' : 'bottom';
                },

                clip: false
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div style="height:500px">
    <canvas id="chart1"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.3.0/chart.umd.js"
        integrity="sha512-CMF3tQtjOoOJoOKlsS7/2loJlkyctwzSoDK/S40iAB+MqWSaf50uObGQSk5Ny/gfRhRCjNLvoxuCvdnERU4WGg=="
        crossOrigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.2.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js" integrity="sha512-JPcRR8yFa8mmCsfrw4TNte1ZvF1e3+1SdGMslZvmrzDYxS69J7J49vkFL8u6u8PlPJK+H3voElBtUCzaXj+6ig==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

The idea behind this is to have datalabels enabled for all bars from the dataset, but choose the one that is correctly positioned to represent the sum from the `formatter` - namely the last dataset whose value (for the current `dataIndex`) has the same sign as the sum. Things might be different if the [`order`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#general) option were used.

The code also uses the fact that the `context` object is shared, *for the same `datasetIndex`*, between the `formatter`, `align` and `anchor` methods, `formatter` being always the first -- if `formatter` returns `null` the others are not even called. Thus, it saves the sum for the current `datasetIndex` in the `context` object to be used by the only one point (per `datasetIndex`) for which `align` and `anchor` are called. For a safer solution, that doesn't use this undocumented fact, one may **recompute the sum** in `align` and `anchor`, or **cache the sum using an external object**, which can be a solution to optimise the computation by only computing the sum once, for the first time the `formatter` is called for a dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`chartjs-plugin-datalabels`](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#configuration) as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3WQQkuEJ3M).

```
Chart.defaults.set('plugins.datalabels', {
  color: '#FE777B'
});

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  options: {
    plugins: {
      // Change options for ALL labels of THIS CHART
      datalabels: {
        color: '#36A2EB',
        anchor: ()=>/*your condition here*/
      }
    }
  },
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      // Change options only for labels of THIS DATASET
      datalabels: {
        color: '#FFCE56'
      }
    }]
  }
});
```

Also checkout the [positioning](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/positioning.html#anchoring) property.